# How to do the equivalent of a 'Tsql select into',  into an existing table 

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

using tsql, sqlserver 2005.

I would like insert records from table table2 into an **existing** table table1
as easily as I could enter it into a new table table1 using:

```
select facilabbr, unitname, sortnum into table1 from table2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT facilabbr, unitname, sortnum FROM table2
```

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you just want to *append* and that the columns match up:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    SELECT facilabbr, unitname, sortnum FROM table2
```

If you want to *replace* and the columns still match:

```
Truncate Table1
INSERT INTO Table1
    SELECT facilabbr, unitname, sortnum FROM table2
```

If you want to replace and the columns do not match:

```
DROP Table1
SELECT facilabbr, unitname, sortnum INTO Table1 FROM table2
```

Comment: Yes this syntax works, but if you are not doing this ad hoc and are going to re-use the code, it is always a better idea to include the column list in the INSERT portion.  I've been working on a series of "bad habits" articles, and this is certainly one of them.  http://is.gd/4ucu2

Comment: "and that the columns match up" - does this require that they match exactly, or only that the destination HAS the columns that are being sent?

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 T1 (T1.FIELD1, T1.FIELD2)
SELECT (T2.FIELD1, T2.FIELD2)
FROM TABLE2 T2
```

should work.